# Eclipse/OSGi: How to control the file-name created via an exported plugin (jar)

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi

Trying to control the name of the file created via Export when exported an OSGi plugin from Eclipse. This is specifically by selecting the plug-in the Project Explorer, then selecting the menus: 'Export | Deployable plugins and fragments'. The options seem limited or almost non existent. For example, if I have plugin called MyPlugin, and I export it, I can dictate the output folder but I can't change the name (it is always 'MyPlugin'...), and it always appends a date code, such as 201506041521. That tag (the Qualifier Replacement) always shows up, even if I unselect the check-mark for it in the Options panel of the Export Dialog.

Essentially, I'm trying to be able to replace an exact bundle-jar, so that I can then call update to update the installed bundle contents. As it is, I have to save the bundle, then go in an rename it to the old version, which is a pain.

Is there anyway to change this to exactly specify the name or at least get rid of the Qualifier Replacement tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualifier is in the MANIFEST.MF file in the Version Tag. Remove it there.

Comment: Thx Peter, I actually figured it out on my own before u answered, but it took way too long.